# Python: Is there a way to have a constructor for a class generate an instance of one of its subclasses?

Tags: python-3.x

I'm wondering if there's a way to have construction of a class, A, actually return an instance of one of its subclasses, based on some evaluation done in A.**new**()? The following doesn't work, but conveys the idea:

```
class A:
    def __new__(self, subclass):
        if subclass == "B":
            return B()
        else:
            return C()

class B(A):
    def __new__(self):
        print("B initialized")

class C(A):
    def __new__(self):
        print("C initialized")
```

If I try the above when trying to assign a new instance to a variable, I get None assigned.

```
>>>x = A("B")
B initialized
>>>print(type(x))
<class 'NoneType'>
>>>print(isinstance(x, B))
False
```

But I want x to be an instance of B (and A).

Comment: What do you mean with generate? do you want to convert one class to the other?

Comment: Using my hypothetical example, if you do x = A("B"), then get back an instance of B (which by inheritance is also an instance of A).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In theory, yes, you can do this. But in practice, it's going to be fiddly and an alternative constructor is a much better way to do this rather than making it a feature of the base class `__new__` method.

First off, the reason your current code doesn't work is that your `__new__` methods in `B` and `C` don't do what they need to do, which is create an instance of those subclasses and return it. Unfortunately fixing them is not entirely trivial, since the natural way to create an instance (by calling `super().__new__`) won't work because `A.__new__` is already involved in the process. You can bypass it, or maybe do an alternative approach.

Here's a mostly conventional way to do things, but with `__new__` methods in the subclasses that bypass the base class to construct instances of themselves.

```
class A:
    def __new__(cls, subclass):
        if subclass == "B":
            return B()
        else:
            return C()

class B(A):
    def __new__(cls):
        print("B initialized")
        return object.__new__(cls)  # we need to bypass A.__new__ here, so no super()

class C(A):
    def __new__(cls):
        print("C initialized")
        return object.__new__(cls)  # here too
```

An alternative might be to make the subclasses not do anything with regard to construction (no `__new__` methods, only `__init__`), and for `A.__new__` to take care of creating the subclass instances directly. This is a bit awkward though because the `__init__` method of the subclasses needs to accept the same arguments as the parent class `__new__` method, even though it probably doesn't need to be told that it was the chosen subclass:

```
class A:
    def __new__(cls, subclass):
        if subclass == "B":
            cls = B
        else:
            cls = C
        return super().__new__(cls)  # directly build the subclass instances ourself

class B(A):
    def __init__(self, subclass): # need to take subclass here, not anything else
        super().__init__()
        print("B initialized")

class C(A):
    def __init__(self, subclass):
        super().__init__()
        print("C initialized")
```

A much nicer approach would be to make the normal creation process of your classes work normally, and add a separate, alternative constructor as a classmethod. That way it won't get in the way of the normal process of inheritance of `__new__` and `__init__`.

```
class A:
    @classmethod
    def construct_subclass(cls, subclass):   # alternative constructor
        if subclass == "B":
            return B(1, 2)
        else:
            return C("foo")

    # we could have an __init__ or __new__ method too, but it would operate as normal

class B(A):
    def __init__(self, x, y): # these methods now can take alternative arguments
        super().__init__()
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        print("B initialized:", x, y)

class C(A):
    def __init__(self, foo):
        super().__init__()
        self.foo = foo
        print("C initialized:", foo)
```

Comment: This is very helpful. If in the superclass I have return B(), I can tell that B's __new__ function is called since the print statement fires. But if instead I do have __new__ defined in the subclass yet in the superclass I call super().__new__(B), then it seems like B's __new__ is not called since the print statement doesn't fire. Is B's __new__ statement bypassed if object.__new__(B) is called?

Comment: Yes, if `A.__new__` calls `super().__new__` it's getting `object.__new__` (unless you've left out some extra levels of inheritance to simplify the question). The reason to explicitly name `object.__new__` in my second example is that calling `super().__new__` from `B.__new__` gets you `A.__new__`, which would mean infinite recursion (or an argument mismatch, maybe).

Comment: So, I guess another question would be: Would this be considered un-pythonic? (I'm very new to python, and learning what I can do with it, which isn't the same as learning what others familiar with python would expect to encounter.)

Comment: It's a little bit of an anti-pattern to have a hard-coded circular-dependency of the base class referring to the derived classes, who in turn inherit from it. But it's not an exceptionally bad one. A slightly better approach would be to have the derived classes register themselves with the base class (maybe using a decorator). But for a small, self-contained project, you don't necessarily get much from designing for extensibility.

Comment: Thanks for the info. I don't know enough yet to know what "register" or "decorator" mean, but can live with that for now. The potential use case I have in mind is that I'm writing a lib to parse OpenType font files, and certain tables have subtables with several distinct formats; the first word of the subtable indicates the format. So, I could define a subtable class that reads that word and then constructs the appropriate subtable type, and all those details would be encapsulated in the subtable superclass.

Comment: The implementation details of what I was suggesting are very flexible, the general idea is called "dependency injection" if you want to look it up later. You could go even simpler with a top level function (outside of all of your classes), that would examine the data and return an object of the appropriate class. Compare the builtin `open` function in Python, which can return different kinds of file objects depending on what arguments you pass it. That's *sort of* an iffy design, especially these days that lots of people like doing static type checking, but it does work well.